# Ansible group vars not getting loaded

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Group vars are not getting imported. The directory structure looks like this:

```
 - ansible.cfg
 - testt.yaml
 - inventories
     - production 
          - group_vars
                - all.yaml
          - host_vars
          - hosts
     - staging
          - group_vars
                - all.yaml
                - check99.yaml
          - host_vars
          - hosts
```

ansible.cfg looks like this:

```
     inventory= inventories
```

staging/hosts looks like:

```
     target99 ansible_connection=local
    
     [check99]
     target99
```

staging/group_vars/check99.yaml looks like:

```
      hello: abc
```

testt.yaml looks like:

```
    - hosts: target99
      tasks: 
         - debug:
             msg: >
                {{hello}}
```

When I run command:  ansible-playbook testt.yaml, I get error variable hello undefined, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the inventory to an incorrect directory

Try setting the inventory in ansible.cfg

```
inventory=inventories/staging/
```